# Purpose of head, title, body tag in HTML email

Tags: php, html-email, swiftmailer

I want to send a php email with a clickable hyperlink. The hyperlink is so long that most programs are not able to detect the url from plain-text, therefore, I want to use a HTML-Email. Im using SwiftMailer and I know that I should set a plain-text Email first and then I can add a html-email to it.

At http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php I found the following example of how to write a HTML email:

```
// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
    <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
';
```

Is it important to set

```
<html>, <head> and <body>?
```

Where does

```
<title>
```

appear at? Should the title be the same as the subject? Or could I just set the message like that:

```
// message
$message = '
<p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
</tr>
</table>
';
```

Answer (score 3):

No, the `<title>` tag has no effect in the resulting e-mail. But you should probably keep the other parts of the HTML valid – it *should* not be required and most e-mail agents *should* be able to handle it, but you know – better be safe :-) .

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a email that you are writing, it's just a html file. So you're code here is in other  words just a website.

Comment: There are many reasons why an email may take a web page-esque format.

Answer (score 0):

Title is only important if you have a 'web version' of your email. It will display as it would in a normal web page.

Head is important for your `<style>` declarations, although some clients strip it and only display the contents of the `<body>`. Some people have experimented in the past putting the style tag in the body to cheat the support in those clients. I haven't heard anything about it being successful however (It could have actually broken in other clients).

It is common practice to just stick with using the `<head>` tag for `<style>` (and then inline also).